# I want some options to be visible according to the type selected in the form in flutter

Tags: flutter

[image]

Here as shown in the above picture I want to display another textFormField (say NO.of Floors) if apartment is selected and the other fields also have different TextFields to be diplayed when they are selected.

I have tried adding Visibility but it does not works,While i select apartment i have to hotreload to update the ui and get the no.of floors field and once it came,though i click on another option it does not get hidden.

```
    import 'dart:io';

import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

import '../strings/colors.dart';
import '../strings/images.dart';

class BuilderAddProperty extends StatefulWidget {
  const BuilderAddProperty({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<BuilderAddProperty> createState() => _BuilderAddPropertyState();
}

class _BuilderAddPropertyState extends State<BuilderAddProperty> {
  bool isApartmentSelected = false;
  final ImagePicker imgpicker = ImagePicker();
  List<XFile>? imagefiles;
  final List<String> downloadUrls = [];

  final TextEditingController _imageCountController = TextEditingController();
  void _showSubmitDialog(BuildContext context) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text('Success!'),
          content: Text('Your Listing has been submitted.'),
          actions: <Widget>[
            TextButton(
              child: Text('OK'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }

  String propertyTitle = '';
  String propertyDescription = '';
  String propertyAddress = '';
  String propertyBedRooms = '';
  String propertyBathRooms = '';
  String propertyArea = '';
  String propertyPrice = '';
  String propertyType = '';
  String propertyFloors = '';
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
  String? currentUserId;
  void getCurrentUserId() {
    final User? user = _auth.currentUser;
    if (user != null) {
      currentUserId = user.uid;
    }
  }

  String? _validateTitle(String? value) {
    if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
      return 'Please enter a valid value';
    }
    return null;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Image.asset(
            rlogo,
            fit: BoxFit.contain,
            height: 30,
          ),
          centerTitle: true,
          leading: const Icon(
            Icons.menu,
            color: Color(0xFF242A38),
          ),
          elevation: 0,
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30),
            child: Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  TextFormField(
                    onChanged: (values) {
                      propertyTitle = values;
                    },
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'Property Title',
                        hintText: 'Enter Property Title',
                        border: OutlineInputBorder()),
                    validator: _validateTitle,
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 20),
                  DropdownButtonFormField(
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'Property Type',
                        border: OutlineInputBorder()),
                    items: const [
                      DropdownMenuItem(
                        value: 'Apartment',
                        child: Text('Apartment'),
                      ),
                      DropdownMenuItem(
                        value: 'Plot',
                        child: Text('Plot'),
                      ),
                      DropdownMenuItem(
                        value: 'Villa',
                        child: Text('Villa'),
                      ),
                      DropdownMenuItem(
                        value: 'Farm Land',
                        child: Text('Farm Land'),
                      ),
                      DropdownMenuItem(
                        value: 'Commercial',
                        child: Text('Commercial'),
                      ),
                    ],
                    onChanged: (values) {
                      propertyType = values!;
                      if (propertyType == 'Apartment') {
                        isApartmentSelected = true;
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 20),
                  //
                  //
                  // here is visibility
                  // when i am performing hot reload it is showing the field
                  // and the field remains constant though i select other options
                  //
                  Visibility(
                    visible: isApartmentSelected,
                    child: TextFormField(
                      onChanged: (values) {
                        propertyFloors = values;
                      },
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'No. of Floors',
                        hintText: 'Enter No. of Floors',
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 20),
                  TextFormField(
                    onChanged: (values) {
                      propertyDescription = values;
                    },
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                    maxLines: 5,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'Property Description',
                        hintText: 'Enter Property Description',
                        border: OutlineInputBorder()),
                    validator: _validateTitle,
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 20),
                  TextFormField(
                    onChanged: (values) {
                      propertyAddress = values;
                    },
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                    maxLines: 5,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'Property Address',
                        hintText: 'Enter Property Address',
                        border: OutlineInputBorder()),
                    validator: _validateTitle,
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 20),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 50,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    child: ElevatedButton.icon(
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        backgroundColor: rNavyGrey,
                      ),
                      onPressed: () async {
                        try {
                          var pickedfiles = await imgpicker.pickMultiImage();
                          if (pickedfiles != null) {
                            imagefiles = pickedfiles;
                            _imageCountController.text =
                                '${imagefiles!.length} image(s) selected';
                            setState(() {});
                          } else {
                            print("No image is selected.");
                          }
                        } catch (e) {
                          print("error while picking file.");
                        }
                      },
                      icon: Icon(Icons.upload),
                      label: Text(
                        'Upload Images From Gallery',
                        style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 10),
                  TextFormField(
                    controller: _imageCountController,
                    enabled: false,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                    ),
                  ),
                  // const SizedBox(height: 20),
                  TextFormField(
                    onChanged: (values) {
                      propertyBedRooms = values;
                    },
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'No of Bed Rooms',
                        hintText: 'Enter Number Of Bed Rooms',
                        border: OutlineInputBorder()),
                    validator: _validateTitle,
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 20),
                  TextFormField(
                    onChanged: (values) {
                      propertyBathRooms = values;
                    },
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'No of Bath Rooms',
                        hintText: 'Enter Number Of Bath Rooms',
                        border: OutlineInputBorder()),
                    validator: _validateTitle,
                  ),

                  const SizedBox(height: 20),
                  TextFormField(
                    onChanged: (values) {
                      propertyArea = values;
                    },
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'Area (in sqft)',
                        hintText: 'Enter Area In Sqft',
                        border: OutlineInputBorder()),
                    validator: _validateTitle,
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 20),
                  TextFormField(
                    onChanged: (values) {
                      propertyPrice = values;
                    },
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'Price (in Rupees)',
                        hintText: 'Enter Price Of The Listing',
                        border: OutlineInputBorder()),
                    validator: _validateTitle,
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 20),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 50,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        backgroundColor: rNavyGrey,
                      ),
                      onPressed: () async {
                        if (_formKey.currentState?.validate() == true) {
                          getCurrentUserId();
                          _formKey.currentState!.save();

                          // upload images to firebase storage and get the download URLs
                          if (imagefiles != null && imagefiles!.isNotEmpty) {
                            int image_count_title = 1;
                            for (var imagefile in imagefiles!) {
                              try {
                                var task = await storage
                                    .ref(
                                        'property_images/$propertyTitle+$image_count_title')
                                    .putFile(File(imagefile.path));
                                if (task.state == TaskState.success) {
                                  var downloadUrl = await storage
                                      .ref(
                                          'property_images/$propertyTitle+$image_count_title')
                                      .getDownloadURL();
                                  downloadUrls.add(downloadUrl);
                                }
                                image_count_title++;
                              } catch (e) {
                                print("error while uploading image: $e");
                              }
                            }
                          }

                          CollectionReference buildercollRef = FirebaseFirestore
                              .instance
                              .collection('builderData');
                          buildercollRef.add({
                            "Property Title": propertyTitle,
                            "Property Description": propertyDescription,
                            "Bed Rooms": propertyBedRooms,
                            "Bath Rooms": propertyBathRooms,
                            "Property Area": propertyArea,
                            "Property Price": propertyPrice,
                            "Property Address": propertyAddress,
                            "Property Type": propertyType,
                            "Builder Id": currentUserId,
                            "Property Cover": downloadUrls[0],
                          });
                          CollectionReference advisorcollRef = FirebaseFirestore
                              .instance
                              .collection('advisorData');
                          advisorcollRef.add({
                            "Property Title": propertyTitle,
                            "Property Description": propertyDescription,
                            "Bed Rooms": propertyBedRooms,
                            "Bath Rooms": propertyBathRooms,
                            "Property Area": propertyArea,
                            "Property Price": propertyPrice,
                            "Property Type": propertyType,
                            "Property Address": propertyAddress,
                            "Property Cover": downloadUrls[0],
                          });
                          _showSubmitDialog(context);
                        }

                        /////////
                      },
                      child: Text(
                        'Submit Now',
                        style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't see the visibility widget in your code, are you sure you are using it?

Comment: i have updated my code once see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update your app state with the new isApartmentSelected value

try this:

```
if (propertyType == 'Apartment') {
    setState(() {
      isApartmentSelected = true;
    });
}
```